2d Ising model with a longitudinal field -- do the low and high temperature expansions converge for all nonzero $T$?
The 2d Ising model has a ferromagnetic and a paramagnetic phase separated by a critical $K_c$.
The paramagnetic phase is often understood via a high-temperature expansion of the free-energy in powers of $\tanh(K)$. The high-temperature expansion for the free energy density only has a finite radius of convergence in thermodynamic limit, which is often identified with the fact that the high-temperature expansion does not describe the low temperature phase. I am trying to understand if the converse of this behavior is true.
If I add a longitudinal field $h>0$, as in $H = - \sum_{\langle i j \rangle} \sigma_i \sigma_j - h \sum_i \sigma_i$, I believe there is no phase transition on varying $T$. Does this mean the high temperature expansion and/or low temperature expansions at fixed $h>0$ converge for all nonzero positive $T$?
I suspect they will still have finite radii of convergence because of some non-analytic behavior elsewhere in the complex $T$ plane, but I don't have a great reason to expect this.

The following is a partial answer. I realized shortly after posting my question that there is a good reason to expect that the high temperature expansion will have finite radius of convergence in $T$ when $h$ is sufficiently small. At small negative $T$, the model should correspond to an antiferromagnet under a field, which should be able to host an antiferromagnetically ordered phase at sufficiently small $h$. Thus there should be a nonanalyticity in the free energy for small negative $T$, which will rule out the convergence of the high temperature expansion for all positive $T$ (since failure to converge for $\tanh(K) < -A$ should imply failure to converge for $\tanh(K) > A$).
This rules out convergence of the high-temperature expansion for all positive $T$ when $h$ is small. This argument doesn't yet suffice when $h$ is sufficiently strong (which would rule out a negative-$T$ antiferromagnetic phase). However, there might be another argument that can work when $h$ is large.
